# java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream on aws s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream

I want to process a file using aws s3 bucket with java.

My Code

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
// Get the object from the event and show its content type
String srcBucket = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getBucket().getName();
String srcKey = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getObject().getKey();

S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, srcKey));
audioInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();

processInputStreamMethod1(audioInputStream);

processInputStreamMethod2(audioInputStream);
```

Obviously I get a

> java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream

what is the best way (best practice) to deal with this? Should I copy the Stream with a byte array, close the stream or close the s3Object?

I am new to S3 and InputStreams

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not read the input stream twice but you can copy it with org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils to a byte array and reuse it.

Comment: You could... but beware the size of the stream!  That could be a big memory buffer.

Answer (score 1):

**Depending on whether Method 1 and 2 are dependent...**

If *dependent*... (i.e. Method 1 needs to run before Method 2 in sequence - I can't see why from your question)

Make the stream processing methods a 'filter' that pass through the stream (either modified or unmodified)

i.e.

```
outputStream = processInputStreamMethod2(processInputStreamMethod1(audioInputStream))
```

If *independent*... (which is what it seems from your example since they are both trying to read the 'audioInputStream' directly)

Why do these things in sequence?

Download to a byte array and process both methods in parallel across this array in this code,

```
audioInputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
int audioInputLength = s3object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength();
byte[] content = new byte[audioInputLength];

int bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(content);

//Can be in parallel 
processInputStreamMethod1(content);
processInputStreamMethod2(content);
```

or, if you have the freedom (bandwidth isn't a concern) have two processes each with their own stream?

It all depends on what your context is.

Comment: after writing this... I found... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402711/cloning-multiple-reading-an-input-stream-from-an-httpresponse  - Which says about the same thing!